# Firebase log event not showing any value for the captured event?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase [Log Events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events) to log an event and I am passing a bundle to that event, but the thing is this event is successfully captured by firebase and is visible in their console but when I am checking for values(which I assigned in bundle params) they are not coming.

Can anybody please help me why is this happening?

App.java

```
mAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("type", "" + 1);
mAnalytics.logEvent("user_type", params);
```

Comment: Please add the code that you using for that.

Comment: @AlexMamo Got anything?

Comment: Please add the logs that you're getting.